# crear agrupacion por rango de edad con bash

Tags: bash

tengo el siguiente dataset:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
5,0,3,"Allen, Mr. William Henry",male,35,0,0,373450,8.05,,S
6,0,3,"Moran, Mr. James",male,,0,0,330877,8.4583,,Q
7,0,1,"McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J",male,54,0,0,17463,51.8625,E46,S
8,0,3,"Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard",male,2,3,1,349909,21.075,,S
9,1,3,"Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)",female,27,0,2,347742,11.1333,,S
10,1,2,"Nasser, Mrs. Nicholas (Adele Achem)",female,14,1,0,237736,30.0708,,C
```

Quiero un script con una agrupación hecha según grupos de edad:

- 0-30
- 31-60
- 61-99

Cómo podría hacerlo?

`sort` no me permite elegir grupos y no tengo claro qué otras opciones hay.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tecnología piensas usar? ¿Qué salida querrías para esta entrada? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Le puedes dar una ojeada a `datamash`.